# How to obtain 'basic' type from Type that contains generic parameters?

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I am inspecting a set of Type objects. I am not able to determine how to pull out the 'basic' portion of a type that contains generic parameters.

ie. How to get `Aaa` from `typeof(Aaa<Bbb>)`

The `Bbb` portion is available via the `GenericTypeArguments` array. There is a `BaseType` property, but it returns `typeof(object)`.

It seems like I could parse the `FullName` property to determine the type, but there must be a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you might be looking for [`GetGenericTypeDefinition`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getgenerictypedefinition%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> Returns a [`Type`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) object that represents a generic type definition from which the current generic type can be constructed.

So:

```
typeof(Aaa<Bbb>);
```

Gives you, as you've observed, the type object for `Aaa<Bbb>`. Whereas:

```
typeof(Aaa<Bbb>).GetGenericTypeDefinition();
```

Will give you the type object for `Aaa<T>`<sup>1</sup> (or whatever the type parameter name is for `Aaa`). From which you can e.g. construct other generic types by supplying new type parameters via [`MakeGenericType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.makegenerictype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Of course, if you just want to get the open generic type via a [`typeof()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/58918ffs.aspx) expression, you could just use:

```
typeof(Aaa<>);
```

---

<sup>1</sup>In CLR terms, this is

```
Aaa`1
```

rather than `Aaa<T>` but I've stuck with C# terms in this answer.